# Advanced Policy Analysis

Tags: windows-server-2008, audit, analysis

I am trying to find a way to analyze the Advanced Audit Policies.  Something like the Security Configuration and Analysis tool.  This tools works for the local policy, but doesn't work for the Advanced Audit Policies.  I am on Server 2008.  Is template that I can compare to other systems and generate something that shows how they differ in regards to the policy settings? My system is one of many standalones.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the Security and Compliance manager.  This will import the policies and generate consistent policies.  It's available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53353)